# Implementing links in realtime chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, socket.io

So I'm making a realtime chat with socket.io and node.js, and I have the chat and everything working, but if somebody links a website in the chat, I want it to be an hyperlink automatically.

I'm using autolinker.js to do this, and it's making the links as I want, but my problem is the way I output messages to avoid HTML injections.

```
for(var x = data.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    var autolinker = new Autolinker();
    var linkedText = autolinker.link(data[x].message);
    var message = document.createElement('div');
    var linkOfMessage;
    message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
    //message.textContent = data[x].name + ': ';

    message.innerHTML = data[x].name + ': ' + linkedText;

    // Append
    messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
    messages.appendChild(message);
    messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
    }
```

So the message is getting handled correctly, but with innerHTML, they can basically use scripts inside my chat, which is bad. But

```
message.textContent = data[x].name + ': ' + linkedText;
```

Will just display my hyperlink in plain text without it being clickable, is there anyway to do this without setting the site at risk?

I've spent a couple of hours looking around and couldn't fint anything related to this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always sanitize user input. You want links, so you have to allow some html tags in messages, but you want to filter out most of them (some are dangerous, like script, and some could "damage" your chat visuals). Try experimenting with packages such as

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html

It's not a good idea to roll your own sanitizer. Packages like this allow to specify which tags to allow, which to remove and have various other, helpful options.

Comment: This package seems to work fine, you get to pick which tags you allow.